# how to find xy coordinates value from another xy vlaue in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, canvas

I have detect car image to get x, y pixel value. Now i need to find another x, y pixel value from 90 degree.
Tried some method but it did not work:

```
 exports.strokeLine=(request, response)=>{

function lineDistance( point1, point2 ){
    var xs = 0;
    var ys = 0;

    xs = point2.x - point1.x;
    xs = xs * xs;

    ys = point2.y - point1.y;
    ys = ys * ys;

    return Math.sqrt( xs + ys );
}

// var pos = lineDistance(206.543869972229, 204.03305053710938);
var pos2 = lineDistance(206.543869972229, 204.03305053710938 );

//show result of end point
 console.log(pos2);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written your `lineDistance` function it expects two arguments in the form of `{ x: Number, y: Number }`, so two point objects, each with an `x` and a `y` coordinate. Since you are only passing it two numbers in your example it won't work.

See below for a working example:

```js
function lineDistance( point1, point2 ){
    let xs = point2.x - point1.x;
    xs = xs * xs;

    let ys = point2.y - point1.y;
    ys = ys * ys;

    return Math.sqrt( xs + ys );
}


const pos = lineDistance({x : 206.54, y: 300.76}, {x : 204.03, y: 505.37});

document.querySelector(".distance").textContent = pos;
```

```html
<p class="distance"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. how to get pixel by giving two number and angle ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want... with the fix above you can calculate the [euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between two points. I assumed that's what you needed based on the code. But if you want to find a new point that's something entirely different. Where should that point be? If you just have an _angle_ that is not enough to find _new coordinates_ you would also need a _distance_. Maybe take a look at the [polar coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)